# Possible to resize height & keeping aspect ratio of block element like an image with just CSS?

Tags: html, css

My problem is more or less identical [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div), but with the slight difference that I need to vertically resize it.

What I mean is; according to the information supplied in the article I linked to, the DIV will resize while keeping the aspect ratio if you stretch/contract the browser **width**, but not if you make the browser window taller/shorter (ie, its **height**) - I wonder if it's possible to make this work in a CSS-only environment.

TYIA.

Comment: If you would like a css solution, don't use the javascript tag...

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with just an image, then setting its width to 100% and removing its height will keep its aspect rate, but obviously will also degrade its quality at great stretchings.

Like this:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm not working with an image, which you can see by following the link I supplied. What I want is an element (eg, a DIV-element) to work like an image when scaling its height.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible.

The closest thing that is possible is described in the answer to this question: [Make an element's width relative to its height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876932/make-an-elements-width-relative-to-its-height)

...however, that requires introducing an `img` tag into the source.